# Hudson copying files with Robocopy

Tags: robocopy, hudson

I have hudson setup on a CI server, I'm using robocopy to copy files across to a webserver.

I'm having some problems with exit codes. Robocopy reports so many different exit codes for success and failure, hudson doesn't understand them and reports anything other than 0 as a failure.

I though I'd managed to get around this by calling robocopy to do the same job twice. So the first time it does the task and returns a non-zero exit code and the next time it has nothing to copy so returns a 0. This works when I click the build button on Hudson, but not when it's monitoring the git repo for some reason.

So my question is, can I tell hudson about the individual exit codes so that the build succeeds or would I have to create a wrapper around robocopy to provide exit codes that hudson understands?

Cheers

Tom

**UPDATE**
After Peter's answer, I added the following statements at the end of my robocopy script

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 set ERRORLEVEL=0
if ERRORLEVEL 2 set ERRORLEVEL=0
if ERRORLEVEL 3 set ERRORLEVEL=0 
if ERRORLEVEL 5 set ERRORLEVEL=0 
if ERRORLEVEL 6 set ERRORLEVEL=0 
if ERRORLEVEL 7 set ERRORLEVEL=0
```

As anything below an 8 is considered a success for robocopy, this translates the error codes for hudson and reports a success. I'd imagine I could refactor this at some point.

Thank you for your help Peter!

**UPDATE**

Re-factored this with Peter's suggestion:

if %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 7 set ERRORLEVEL=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy. You have to translate the error codes for Hudson. I use the following statement after my robocopy

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 set ERRORLEVEL=0
```

I googled for error codes of robocopy and found the following page. You can search the microsoft pages too for the error codes.

http://www.mysidenotes.com/2008/02/15/robocopy-errorlevel-return-codes-found-in-robocopydoc/

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter.

Would this work for other error levels too?

Could I add a new if statement for each error level?

if ERRORLEVEL 1 set ERRORLEVEL=0
if ERRORLEVEL 2 set ERRORLEVEL=0
if ERRORLEVEL 3 set ERRORLEVEL=0

Comment: yes it would. Have a look at the link I posted in my answer, that's what they are doing. You can also use operators like `IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 2 set ERRORLEVEL=0` have a look at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntif.php for more compare operators.